# How can I round up a single edge of a plane?

Tags: vertex-groups

How can I round up a single edge of a plane?

I hope the pictures help to understand the question.

I'm using Blender v.2.78

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished with the **Edge Fillet Plus** utility in the **Edit Tools 2** addon. First, enable this addon in user preferences.

[image: Edit Tools 2]

Then use the **W** menu in **Edit Mode** with the two edges selected:

[image: Using the edit tools]

This process converts the face to an N-Gon. To fill this shape, **Alt + Right Click** the line to loop select as shown above and hit **F** to fill the area.

Comment: You should also be aware when using N-Gon's https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89/when-should-n-gons-be-used-and-when-shouldnt-they

Comment: can you provide a link to the addon?

Comment: @AlexanderHein The addon should be in Blender by default, but you can read more about it on the blender wiki: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/Extra_Tools

Answer (score 2):

### A fairly simple way to create rounded corners

No add-ons required. Uses quad topology.

[image: Creating rounded corners on a plane]

- Loop Cut to create holding edges <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>
- Select and Delete the corner vertex <kbd>X</kbd>
- Select the vertex that will be at the center for the Spin radius
- Snap Cursor to Selection <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>
- Select the outermost vert and Spin it [image: The Spin button] (Viewport orientation matters, look straight-on)
- Adjust the Spin parameters (I used 6 steps at a 90° angle) in the Operator Panel
- Switch to Edge Selection
- Select the two non-touching edges and Fill <kbd>F</kbd> to make each face.

In some cases you may then also want to Inset <kbd>I</kbd> all your planar geometry:

[image: Insetting the rounded corners surface]

...such as in situations where you plan to SubSurf:

[image: The difference Insetting can make when a Subdivision Surface Modifier is used]

Comment: great. thanks very much, i've been looking for clean quad based topology like this.