# Vertices moving at different rates?

Tags: mesh, transforms, vertices, faces

When I select a group of vertices and use "G" to move them, different vertices move at a different weight, even when snapped to the grid or an axis. It isn't attached to another mesh, armature, and hasn't been weight painted.

[image: screenshot-1]
[image: screenshot-2]

Is there any way I can fix this or am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: I tried removing the mirror modifier completely but it had no effect on it

Comment: I checked the X mirror was off and tested it for both being active and not, and there was sill no difference. i uploaded the file. Thank you for helping me out

Comment: The vertices appear to be moving correctly as a unit.  Maybe the fact that it's deforming the polygons badly is creating an optical illusion.

Comment: It's moving correct as far as I can see. You have Ngons in your model (faces with more than 4 vertices) which are both faces on the sides of the selected part on the screenshot. There are some reasons to not use Ngons while modeling, this is one of them - they get distorted in the areas where Blender splits them (as it can't otherwise). The best way is to convert them to quads. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89/when-should-n-gons-be-used-and-when-shouldnt-they

Comment: Ah, thank you, it was a part of the issue. but even when the faces only had a maximum of four vertices it still acted the same, and it was like this for other parts as well. could it be that i have a dated version of blender?

Comment: @LissoTaylor You have the current version (2.78). It is a matter of how you are looking at it, the two verts at the top move as you expect, the other selected verts behind them are not aligned to them to start with, as you move them they stay offset the same amount from the front verts.  Press Z to go into wireframe display and you can see the verts at the back move at the same time.

Comment: oh huh, i guess it is moving as it should be, i was just expecting it to move on an gradual angle like it does when you have a square with only four vertices on each face. Thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your 3D Cursor around might fix the issue.

The amount of mouse movement converted into 3D translations are based on the distance between the local/selected pivot and the view pivot.  If you set the pivot point to 3D cursor, then the position of the 3D cursor will affect how much of your mouse movement is converted into actual 3D distance.

Objects' scaling transformation also has some play in this.