# Weird shading after extrude, tried everything (i think)

Tags: shaders, extrude, shadows

I am trying to exctrude some faces and after I do it I am getting really weird shading. I have tried:

-splitting nonplanar faces
-removing doubles
-increased vertices

Is there anything else I can try? Anyone know what causes this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to smooth shade an object while retaining hard edges?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734/how-to-smooth-shade-an-object-while-retaining-hard-edges)

Comment: The weird shading comes from the [ngons](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89/when-should-n-gons-be-used-and-when-shouldnt-they/95#95) in your mesh.

Answer (score 1):

Add an Edge Split modifier. Ideally, you would redo/alter all the letters to have no more that 4 vertices per face.