# Why does Blender allow faces whose vertices are not on a single plane?

Tags: faces, geometry

I dissolved one corner of a cube:

[image]

And got this weird face:

[image]

It doesn't make sense to me cause it's not a "face" in a geometrical sense. Why do faces like this exist in Blender and is there any usage of them?

Comment: they are called ngons

Comment: Under the hood it's all triangles. Blender doesn't draw their edges outlines but they are here. And there isn't mutch use for this, unless you're going for a weird looking render.

Comment: As mentioned by the comments, they are N-gons, and this related post I think is useful: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89/when-should-n-gons-be-used-and-when-shouldnt-they

Comment: A face is agnostic of what's going on in the world around it. All it knows is the index of the edges which it is linked to. There is no upper limit to this number, thus creating N-Gons is possible. It is your responsibility to create a "coplanar" face, or else the engine will have to decide "randomly" how to triangulate your mesh when rendering it.