# Is this possible to avoid ngon in this case?

Tags: subdivision-surface, topology

I have this curved surface:

[image: faces]

With subdiv modifier it looks exactly as I want:

[image: side]
[image: top]

So is this the only way to get such a geometry? If I add a connection between vertices, it changes the shape of subdivided mesh.

Comment: There is not necessarily anything wrong with having n-gons if it produces a topology you are happy with after subdivision, particularly if the n-gons are coplanar (which they are here). Is there a particular reason you would like to avoid the n-gons in this case? Or are you just asking a question about “good hygiene,” so to speak?

Comment: I just watched some Blender course and the guy said that you always have to avoid ngons. Maybe I took it too literally :D

Comment: Yes, there are people telling you to avoid ngons. And there are definitely reasons and cases where this is applicable, but it is not necessary (I'd even call it nonsense) to _always_ avoid them. Blender works good with quads, but ngons often work as well. Other programs might prefer triangles. Things like Loop Cuts (Ctrl+R) will neither work with ngons nor triangles. But there are even tutorials on Youtube where people explain when ngons might be even better than trying to make all quads.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should N-Gons be used, and when shouldn't they?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89/when-should-n-gons-be-used-and-when-shouldnt-they)