# Error uploading Blender character to Mixamo

Tags: animation, rigging

I'm a student that just created my first character in Blender. I want to upload my character in Mixamo to animate it. I exported it as a OBJ file and FBX file but I kept getting errors by uploading my character to mixamo. I read some posts on the community forums which allowed me to tweak my character and uploaded it to mixamo. However, she's missing her face and hair. Does anyone have any suggestions, I have included my blender file and screenshots.

I've recently worked out that it is the hair of my character, but I am unsure on how to fix.

This is what my character looks like in blender

This is what happens when i insert my character into mixamo.

[image]
[image]
I have uploaded my character to google drive.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/18YbvLow-d8qLw_e06SIYld3P41KHh8iK/view?usp=sharing

Any suggestions I would be greatful for your help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is mostly the bad mesh that causes the problems. You should fix the model first before you animate it.

**1)** the *head* has several problems:
[image: bad mesh]

- there is a hole in the neck! Remove the neck completely. Then select the edge loop around the hole where the neck should be and extrude it (<kbd>E</kbd>) down along the Z-axis (<kbd>Z</kbd> to lock the axis).
- there is a "block" under her nose. Remove the bad faces and rebuild them. It's just a few.
- in the area along the jawline and around the ears there are split and duplicated vertices.  It looks like the mesh isn't connected completely. There are gaps and intersections. That's the worst part.

**2)** not a major issue but worth notable: in front of the armpit is a 6-star pole. This can deform badly, especially in this area. The faces right next to it are very thin. Move it a bit around.

**3)** the "white mask" in screenshot 1 of your question is the prototype/backup object in the *Archive* collection and the hidden *Cylinder.001* (neck). You can limit the export to selected objects only. Select everything except the *Archive* and tick the *Limit To `[X]` Selection Only* checkbox in the export dialog.

**4)** the hair has way too many vertices, almost **600,000!** That's too many for an animation. You can use the *Remesh* modifier (option `Smooth`, Octree Depth: `6`) that also fixes the holes which the mesh has. Make a copy of the mesh and you can bake a normal map from the high-poly version to bring the details back. Low-poly hair with 15,000 vertices:
 [image: low-poly hair]

Note: After you reduced the number of vertices of the hair mesh the blend file size will shrink from 66 MB to 3 MB.

**5)** the body has some filled [N-gon areas](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89/when-should-n-gons-be-used-and-when-shouldnt-they). This can result in bad deformation and you can't select edge loops easily to work with the mesh. This should be fixed. Use the knife tool, <kbd>K</kbd> in *Edit* mode, to add the missing edges: 
[image: ngons in the mesh]

**6)** the *head* and the *body* meshes have duplicated verts. Get rid of them by selection everything in *Edit* mode with key <kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>M</kbd>, *Merge By Distance*.

Comment: Thankyou so much for you help it worked!

Comment: If so, please consider to accept the answer @TyneshaSouthan How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour, please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers