# How do I make a smooth shaded mesh not look weird?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, shaders, edit-mode, object-mode

I'm someone who wants to try and make a game and modelling is one o the aspects I'm trying to learn. I'm new here in blender and I don't know a whole bunch yet. But I'm trying to cut a shape of a lego (roblox) head:
[image: head mesh]

and shading it smooth:
[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see, the smooth shade makes the mesh look weird in some place and I'm wondering how to fix it.

[image]

Here's another picture in edit mode and yes, there are a lot of N-gons on the curves I made and I heard those make smooth shading look weird. Another thing to note is that I'm going to solidify the mesh so it doesn't look paper thin. But the result came out like this:

[image]

Here's what I did to make the shape:

1. I took a loop of the head, seperate it, and turned it into a curve
2. I modelled the curve using the edge slide tool to move the vertices on the surface of the head, return it to a mesh then join it with the head.
3. I then deleted half of the head and make a new vertex path for every edges that looks connected with the head and fill it.
4. I used the smooth shade option

Here's what I've tried to do:

1. Check if the vertices are on the right coordinates
2. Try to convert the N-gons to triangular faces
3. Try subdividing and converting to triangular faces

I really hope someone could help me with this, thanks!

Here's a link to my blend file (Don't mind my amateur models please!): [image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89/when-should-n-gons-be-used-and-when-shouldnt-they/

Comment: Sorry for the late response but thanks for the answer! Yes, N-Gons are not good for what I'm about to do (exporting after finished) which is why I'm now trying to remove them. I tried to make the whole mesh to triangles and turn them back to quads. The result in smooth shading is fairly better but the irregular shadows still appears. Any other suggestions on what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Select the object, right click and select auto smooth.
[image: process]

Comment: Hello! Again, sorry for the late response. I tried to use the auto smooth after but it still results on the same weird shading. Are there any other ways to fix it?

Comment: Oh. Try using a weighted normals modifer. If that doesn't work can you share your blend file?

Comment: Heya! Thanks for the help again. Unfortunately after trying the weighted normal modifier, the same weird shading still persists. Probably because I'm unfamiliar to the use of the modifier. I'll include the blend file on my edited question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Or maybe try this: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=Jpkxk2y2" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/Jpkxk2y2/)